# How to deploy code from local git repository to remote server using Ansible

Tags: git, ansible

I am using Ansible 2.5. I need to do deploy code from local(controller) git repository to remote server.

I was trying with a Ansible-playbook with git module that can only deploy code from local repository to another local path or remote repository to another remote path. Its based on hosts configuration.

```
- git:
    repo: /home/pi/Desktop/kk/Vue-Example/
    dest: /home/pi/Desktop/bb
```

Here `repo` will be local(controller-machine) git repository path
and `dest` will be remote machine location.

Comment: and what is the problem ? what result did u get when trying the above ?

Comment: When add `hosts: localhost` that works because localhost I have exist git repository and destination too. it can deploy local->local.  But when adding `hosts: remote-host` that not working. it says remote server have no git repository in that location. I need to deploy local->remote. What will be the configuration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is exactly the workflow I wanted as well - to extract files from a local git repo I know I can depend on. In my case, I use a specific commit ID (a version that has been well-tested) rather than a branch name. If you want this, just replace 'master' below with the commit ID.

```yaml
- tasks:
    - name: Make temp directory
      tempfile:
        state: directory
      register: temp_git_archive
      delegate_to: localhost
      become: no
      changed_when: False
    - name: Extract latest git commit on branch master
      shell: git archive master |tar --extract --directory={{ temp_git_archive.path }}
      args:
        chdir: /home/pi/Desktop/kk/Vue-Example/  # YOUR LOCAL GIT REPO
      delegate_to: localhost
      become: no
      changed_when: False
    - name: Copy to remote
      copy:
        src: "{{ temp_git_archive.path }}"
        dest: /home/pi/Desktop/bb  # YOUR DESTINATION DIRECTORY
    - name: Delete temp directory
      file:
        path: "{{ temp_git_archive.path }}"
        state: absent
      when: temp_git_archive.path is defined
      delegate_to: localhost
      become: no
      changed_when: False
```

It may be possible to use the Ansible 'git' and 'unarchive' modules in place of the 'shell' module above, but I prefer doing it in one step.

Answer (score 1):

You have wrongly interpreted the use of git module of ansible. It is used to clone the remote repo at the dest path i.e either in the controller machine or in the remote hosts. You have specified local path which doesn't exists for git module as git would try to send a http/ssh request and such path doesn't exists.

The quote of the repo value from ansible is

> repo: git, SSH, or HTTP(S) protocol address of the git repository.

In case you are looking to clone on the controller machine reason being ssh keys then you can use the git module delegate to localhost then use the copy module to copy from controller to remote machine

```
---
- name: play to checkout
  hosts: remote-hosts
  tasks:
    - name: git checkout
      repo: "{{ repo_url }}"
      dest: /tmp
      delegate_to: localhost
    - name: copy module
      synchronize:
        src: ...
        dest: ...
```

Comment: `repo: local_or_remote_git_repository` works for me. but it only local to local or remote-> remote based on `hosts:` configuration. Anyway, can you please tell me what will  be the good solution for deploy local -> remote only git changes files.

Comment: that what I said it would work on local to local as the repo exists and git considers it as local repo and it exists on the local machine. You want to checkout at controller machine and copy to remote right ? Then the above would work

Comment: OK, but is it deploy again full application or only git changes?

Comment: in that case you can use the synchronize module of ansible. so you want to copy the modified files from a local controller machine to remote machine - only modified things will be copied but note that everytime you run the repo to local needs to be checkout as in pull from remote

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take:

```yaml
---
- name: Create repo directory
  file:
    path: "{{project_src_destination}}"
    state: directory
- name: Init repo
  command: git init {{project_src_destination}}
  args:
    creates: "{{project_src_destination}}/.git"
- name: Test repo state
  command: git show {{project_branch}}
  args:
    chdir: "{{project_src_destination}}"
  register: result
  ignore_errors: true
  changed_when: result.rc != 0
- name: Upload the repo
  local_action:
    module: command git push ssh://{{inventory_hostname}}/{{project_src_destination}} {{project_branch}}
    chdir: "{{project_src_source}}"
  when: 'result.rc != 0'
- name: Checkout the newly created branch
  command: git checkout {{project_branch}}
  args:
    chdir: "{{project_src_destination}}"
  register: result
  changed_when: "'Switched' in result.stdout"
```

Unlike the previous answer, there is no need to create an intermediary archive. Can be advantageous, if one needs to do incremental updates.

A completely different approach would be just to use rsync:

```yaml
- name: Copy sources
  ansible.posix.synchronize:
    src: "{{project_src_host}}"
    dest: "{{project_src_destination}}"
    delete: true
    rsync_opts:
      - "--exclude=.git"
      - "--exclude=*.pb.go"
      - "--exclude=*.o"
      - "--exclude=*.d"
      - "--filter=:- .gitignore"
```

Here the idea is to mostly rely on `.gitignore` to not copy intermediate compilation results.